# Jupyter Lab - running cell forever with file.close (), print and sys.stdout

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, jupyter-lab

I'm not sure but I imagine that there may be issues similar to mine, but I have not found any that has been satisfactory.

When I open my Jupyter Lab and execute a cell as below (*code01*), it remains with the status of `*` (see *figure01* below) meaning that it is still running the code, but the output of the *out1.txt file* is printed correctly.
I would like to know if it is normal for the cell to remain running in this circumstances described from *code01*.

**code01:**

```
import sys
file = open('out1.txt', 'a')
sys.stdout = file
print("house")
file.close()
```

**figure01:**

[image: cell running forever]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you redirect the stdout to a file and then close it you are breaking the IPython kernel underneath: there is no way for any stdout to be correctly processed by the kernel afterwards (cannot write to a closed file). You can reproduce it by executing your code in the IPython console rather than in a notebook. To fix this you could rebind the original `stdout` back:

```
import sys
file = open('out1.txt', 'a')
stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = file
print("house")
# before close, not after!
sys.stdout = stdout
file.close()
```

But this is still not 100% safe; you should ideally use context managers instead:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('out1.txt', 'a') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print('house')
```

But for this particular case why not to make use the `file` argument of the `print()` function?

```
with open('out1.txt', 'a') as f:
    print('house', file=f)
```